# Cannot reach docker website on host debian

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, debian

I try to serve an application with that docker-compose file took from
https://github.com/solidnerd/docker-bookstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.33
    environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookstack
    - MYSQL_USER=bookstack
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
    - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  bookstack:
    image: solidnerd/bookstack
    depends_on:
    - mysql
    environment:
    - DB_HOST=mysql:3306
    - DB_DATABASE=bookstack
    - DB_USERNAME=bookstack
    - DB_PASSWORD=secret
    volumes:
    - uploads:/var/www/bookstack/public/uploads
    - storage-uploads:/var/www/bookstack/storage/uploads
    ports:
    - "8080:8080"

    # nginx:
        # build: ./nginx
        # depends_on:
          # - bookstack
        # ports:
            # - "80:80"
volumes:
 mysql-data:
 uploads:
 storage-uploads:
```

On Windows, if I go to localhost:8080, it works.
On Debian 10, if I try one of these commands :

```
curl "localhost:8080"
curl "172.17.0.1:8080"
```

It stucks and returns a 502 Proxy error after a while.

Here is the result of docker ps -a

```
45afeda13eab   solidnerd/bookstack   "/bin/docker-entrypo…"   27 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds   80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, :::8080->8080/tcp   app_bookstack_1
953a91c86e7d   mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   31 seconds ago   Up 9 seconds    3306/tcp                                            app_db_1
```

If I uncomment my nginx configuration and use these 2 files :

```
events {
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://bookstack:8080;
        }
    }
}
```

```
FROM nginx:1.20.1
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

Then it works. **Why ?**
I would like to use that without nginx. I thought it was a problem with that application, but I had the same problem with another application. Then I guess problem comes from my Debian.
Could you advice me something to reach localhost:8080 without nginx ?

Comment: when you installed docker on your OS did you install docker-desktop or the Docker daemon? Also, please add `docker ps` output while the Nginx service is **not** used (first configuration)

Comment: I updated my question to show you docker ps.
On Windows I have docker desktop. On debian docker daemon

Comment: Are you sure the image version/tag is correct? When I've searched dockerhub the image versioning is more like *0.21* than *21.05.2*

Comment: Well in my use, I removed ":21.05.2" after "solidnerd/bookstack". So my image is only solidnerd/bookstack. I will change that in the question

Comment: No way to make it work with that bookstack image, but mediawiki docker image works nicely. So I guess bookstack image has a problem